How to change Date Picker format default date in Flutter
I want to change the default flutter (dart) date picker date format. The default format of date picker is
"YYYY/MM/DD". But I want to change to "DD-MM-YYYY".
That is, e.g. from 2024/05/21  to 21-05-2024
Below is my function code base, but this isn't working for me.
Please how do I convert it correctly.
 onTap: () async {
                  await showDatePicker(
                          context: context,
                          initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                          firstDate: DateTime(1960),
                          lastDate: DateTime(2040)
                          )
                      .then((value) {
                    setState(() {
                      dob = value.toString();
                    });
                    
                  });
                },

I have tried,
 onTap: () async {
                  await showDatePicker(
                          context: context,
                          initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                          firstDate: DateTime(1960),
                          lastDate: DateTime(2040)
                          )
                      .then((value) {
                    setState(() {
                      dob = value.toString();
                    });
                    
                  });
                },

And I got,
2024/05/21 instead.
I want to get  21-05-2024

Are you referring  the DateInputTextFiled  which is shown when we click on edit icon?

Yes, anyone will be fine.
Either the DateInputTextFiled or to covert from the default format to  21-05-2024
Thank you.
Please  help me.

To achieve your desired output you can use a package called intl.
First add intl 0.19.0 to your dependencies.
   import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

   // ...

   onTap: () async {
              await showDatePicker(
                      context: context,
                      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                      firstDate: DateTime(1960),
                      lastDate: DateTime(2040)
                      )
                  .then((value) {
                setState(() {
                  DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
                  dob = formatter.format(value);
                });
                
              });
            },


Thank you so much.
This worked for me.
onTap: () async {
await showDatePicker(
context: context,
initialDate: DateTime.now(),
firstDate: DateTime(1960),
lastDate: DateTime(2040)
)
.then((value) {
setState(() {
DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
dob = formatter.format(value!);
});
          });
        },


You're welcome.

This code worked for me.
 onTap: () async {
          await showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                  firstDate: DateTime(1960),
                  lastDate: DateTime(2040)
                  )
              .then((value) {
            setState(() {
              DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
              dob = formatter.format(value!);
            });
            
          });
        },

